# Kendo Menu sub-item class bug

Tags: css, menu, kendo-ui, highlight

You can find a reproduction of this problem here: [JsFiddle: Kendo Menu Bug](http://jsfiddle.net/jharrion_resiliencesw/DcNyP/), I'll be referring to it. Just run the kendo menu initialization of the html:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#nav_menuUl").kendoMenu().show();
});
```

When you create a kendo menu, sub-menu items that expand to the right are not updated correctly when you hover over them and then leave. With the top level menus, when you move the mouse over the item, the item will receive the k-state-border-down (and k-state-hover while the pointer is over it) because the menu has expanded to draw it's children below. If you then move the mouse over a child menu which has children it will get k-state-border-right when it draws the children to the right. When you move the mouse off the menu, the k-state-border-down is removed, but the k-state-border-right is not. If you have a style that is highlighting the menu that has the children open, the highlight will be suck on the children which have children.

I need some suggestions for a work around. Thank you.

Comment: A more important bug: after closing the menu, you can't open it again on Android. I'd consider using something else

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for noticing the issue - the last internal build already addresses it and if you're a customer, you can download it from your account. If you're not, as a workaround you can attach a handler to the close or deactivate events and remove the class from the item. Check the [event documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/menu#events-deactivate) for more information.